# android video from local server error

Tags: android, video, xampp, android-mediaplayer

Hi there I'm working in my android app to run video from my local server XAMPP and I have placed my video in htdocs folder under my XAMPP server folder and I got this piece of code :

this is the .java file code

```
public class video extends Activity {

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.video1);
        final VideoView vv = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.vview);
        MediaController mc = new MediaController(this);
        vv.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
        vv.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("http://10.0.2.2/abc.MP4"));
        vv.requestFocus();
        vv.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
               vv.start();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

and here's my logcat errors

```
03-02 02:12:29.222: E/MediaPlayer(464): error (1, -2147483648)
03-02 02:12:29.242: E/MediaPlayer(464): start called in state 0
03-02 02:12:29.242: E/MediaPlayer(464): error (-38, 0)
03-02 02:12:29.252: E/MediaPlayer(464): Attempt to call getDuration without a valid mediaplayer
03-02 02:12:29.252: E/MediaPlayer(464): error (-38, 0)
03-02 02:12:29.322: E/MediaPlayer(464): Error (1,-2147483648)
03-02 02:12:29.742: E/MediaPlayer(464): Error (-38,0)
03-02 02:12:30.222: E/MediaPlayer(464): Error (-38,0)
```

When I click the button to direct me to video view layout where I should see my video playing I got a "black" blank screen for a moment then the screen changes to a white color for the lower have and black for the upper after that I receive the "this video can't be played" error msg three of them together

Comment: really no body knows how ???!!!!!!!